# Making and distributing iOS App in Spanish

Tags: ios, app-store

I have never done any apps that were anything other than English, so this is a new one for me.  I am building an app for a Spanish company.  They would like (at least for now) the app to be available just in espanol, but available to download worldwide.  What do I need to do in my plist to make it all espanol, and are there any other things I need to set for this?

Comment: Hi, Did only change info.plist worked? as in Xcode 6.3 no option for spanish in Localization native development region para, did need to go for internationalisation concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide only an espanol strings file. Just like you've written English only apps until now, you can make this one espanol only.

Take a look at https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/ and follow the practices so that you can add other languages in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Change the project main language to spanish in the info.plist

[image]

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>es</string>
```

And add Spanish to localizations and remove english after that

Comment: I did this.  Project localizations shows Spanish, and not English, and the info.plist shows es, but all my TableViews still have Back and Edit in English instead of Spanish.

Comment: try with a clean and run again, or even, delete the app from the device/simulator and try again. How do you add the Edit and Back button?

Comment: If I change the Settings Language to Spanish, it will show the Back and Edit buttons in Spanish instead of English.  So, if everything but those are hardcoded, and it will only change based off the Settings of the phone, does it matter if I have it as Spanish localization or English?  I want to sell worldwide, but ONLY want Spanish as the language.

Comment: that shouldn't happen, I have a spanish only app, and the edit button appears as "editar" even if I change the phone language. I just changed the CFBundleDevelopmentRegion to "es", created the spanish localization and removed the english localization. BTW, when I had the CFBundleDevelopmentRegion set to "en", the edit button appeared as "edit" even if the phone language was set to spanish.